# Comparison of regression coefficients, same y but two different X versions

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, poisson-regression, model-comparison

I've seen versions of this question but not specifically answering the question of a statistical test to compare the beta coefficients for two independent variables (x1, x2) but the same dependent variable (y1). In this example, y is a count variable, and x1 and x2 are binary {0,1} (and correlated) variables. So I have run these two regressions:

y1 ~ b1 * x1

y1 ~ b2 * x2

And now I want to statistically compare b1 and b2.

Is there a statistical test to use? Or do I create a model that includes x1 and x2?

I've read several relevant papers, but none address the question of comparing betas in models with the same y:

- Cummings 2009, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/SIM.3471
- Clogg 1995: https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/230638
- Altman: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1125071/

Comment: You can just bootstrap both models and the difference between b1 and b2.

Comment: Thanks, thats definitely a good fallback. I am hoping for a derivation, and have been trying to searching using the keywords "correlated regression coefficients" but no luck yet.

Comment: This might help: [Mize et al. (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1177/0081175019852763). They describe a framework for estimating the covariance between regression coefficient estimates across two models, which can be used to compute the standard error of the difference between the two coefficients. In Stata, this is implemented in the `suest` command.

Comment: Thanks so much! appreciated